# Why are there two plus operators in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

In OCaml operators as `<` do support `int` and `float`.
Why `+` cannot?

Answer (score 2):

Because the `<` operator can support *any* type and not just `int` and `float`.

You couldn't do that with `+` as it wouldn't make sense, say, to add custom-designed types that represent complex data.

On the other hand, having a universal total comparison is extremely useful, as a lot of algorithms and data structure relies on it existing.

Comment: A small additional observation is that an OCaml type can have fully polymorphic parts (as in `'a -> 'a -> bool`. But a type can't have parts that containe an enumeration of specific types (like float and int). So there's no satisfactory way to represent a `+` operator that works on only a few types.